# Retrieve multiple results in a data table

Tags: excel, vba

I have set up this Excel page with approximately 40 rows and 8 columns to compare the financial benefits of 2 different products based on age.

Once I input an age at the top, the next row will have that age +1 for approximately 40 rows, and then the columns beside it will value my products at the new age in every column.

I want certain information from my 5th column, based on the age that is being inputted (I figured out this part). I have a list of ages that I need to use as inputs and want the information from column 5 for each one of those input ages at the same time. I tried using a data table.

To grab the information from column 5 I use this formula: `=INDEX($B$9:$F$49,MATCH(E$55,$B$9:$B$49,),5)`

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "grab"? Do you want to copy each value to some other place? Also, can you assume the list of ages will be sequential?

Comment: if i understand, the age is in column B, and the needed info in column F ?

Comment: Hi fellas, I figured it out this morning thanks for all your help as is

Answer (score 0):

if i understand, the age is in column B, and the needed info in column F ?

Also E55 is the searched Age ?

Then you where near : 
try

```
= INDEX($B$9:$B$49,MATCH(E$55,$B$9:$B$49,),5)
```